# passing in string of an array to an int method not working

Tags: java

I was doing some problem sets from the book, and I came across a function that was I not able to get solve. Need some help with it.

Basically, I wrote a static methods that is accepting any string of arrays; however, it returns an array of integers. Whenever I pass an string of arrays, I am not getting expected out put.

Someone please advice.

```
public static int[] myLengths(String[] myString) {
int x = s.length;
int[] y = new int[x];

for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    y[i] = myString[i].length();
}   

return myString;
```

}

Currently, I am pasting in

```
private static final String[] STRING_ARRAY = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
```

Comment: What input are you passing and what is the expected output?

Comment: What is `s`? Is it `myString.length` or `s.length`

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: You are being very vague in the description of your question, you are also leaving out code that clearly affects provided code. Like "s" for example. What is "s"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume that you want a program that returns the length of strings in an array

```
public static int[] myLengths(String[] myString) {
int x = myString.length;
int[] y = new int[x];

for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    y[i] = myString[i].length();
}   

return y;
}
```

Comment: no prob, pls click the check button if you find my answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

From your code looks like you are trying to get the length of each string inside an array.

You have to return an int[] in the definition:

```
 public static int myLengths(String[] myString) {
```

Should be this:

```
 public static int[] myLengths(String[] myString) {
```

I am not sure what the s is but you should replace it with myString. So your final code should be like this:

```
public static int[] myLengths(String[] myString) {
      int x = myString.length;
      int[] y = new int[x];

      for(int i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
             y[i] = myString[i].length();
       }   

      return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a `String[] myString,` but the method must return an `int[]`

Replace this :

```
public static int[] myLengths(String[] myString) {
```

With

```
public static String[] myLengths(String[] myString) {
```